# IText 7 - Create form with template pages

Tags: java, itext7, xfa

I'm attempting to create a fillable PDF with iText 7. So far I've managed to generate all my pages and fields.  However I'm having a trouble trying to figure out how to make a page an XFA template.

My goal is to create a multipage PDF, with some pages being able to be duplicated.  I'm planning on using the app.spawn JavaScript functionality but in order to do this, the pages need to be marked as templates.

Any idea how I could approach this?

Thank you,

Al

Comment: It's better if you show some code and show the community you have tried to solve the mentioned problem.

Comment: Why do you want to make the page an *XFA* template? Why not simply an *AcroForm* page template? XFA is obsoleted/deprecated after all.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Maybe I'm going at it the wrong way.  I'm attempting to generate a final PDF document so I can distribute it to users.  In this document, there needs to be the ability to duplicate pages, similar to Acrobat JS template/spawn.  Generating the PDF on the fly is not an option at the moment.  The idea is the form can act as a standalone front end with some JS logic built in.

Comment: I'd like to add, working with PDFs, you can mark pages as "template" so that you can then use the JavaScript API to call app.getTemplate('str'), and t.spawn().   At the moment, I'm using iText 7 to create the PDF, I have the javascript to call duplicate the page, however I can't seem to find a way to mark the page as a Template.  I don't believe this is XFA, so that is my fault for using the wrong term.